# unable to locate an ionic element in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Hi I am trying to locate a text box with  below code.getting unable t locate element exception.

```
List<WebElement> productivityButtons = driver.findElements(By.className("app-open-btn"));
for (WebElement item : productivityButtons) {
    String appName = item.getAttribute("appName");

    //System.out.println(item.getText());
    //System.out.println(item.getAttribute("appName"));
    //System.out.println(item.getAttribute("appName"));

    if (item.getAttribute("appName").equals("ReceivingSstkClient")) {
        System.out.println("*****matching");
        System.out.println(item);
        item.click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[id='inputUPCNumber']")).sendKeys("5900020010000");

        //driver.findElementById("inputUPCNumber").sendKeys("5900020010000");
        //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon")).click();

        Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML as well please, and advise at which point your code is failing, post the full exception stack if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: To switch windows before you try and find your element, you will need some code similar to the below:

```
// This is before you click the button to launch the new window and assumes you currently only have one window open
String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

// This is where you click the button to open the "application" window
button.click();

// Now the new window is open we loop through all open browser windows, and find the one that is **not** the window we already had open, then switch to it
for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    if (!handle.equals(currentWindow))
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
}

// Now you can proceed with finding the element you want
```

I'll be able to comment more once you post the relevant HTML, but I believe your current code needs tidying up too:

```
List<WebElement> productivityButtons = driver.findElements(By.className("app-open-btn"));
for (WebElement item : productivityButtons) {
    String appName = item.getAttribute("appName");

    if (appName.equals("ReceivingSstkClient")) {
        item.click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("inputUPCNumber")).sendKeys("5900020010000");
```

You should potentially get rid of `Thread.sleep(2000);` because you have the 'implicitlyWait' (though it's hard to say for sure without knowing what your code after is. And the implicit wait should be moved up to the line after you create your driver object.

Comment: I am selecting an item from a dynamically loaded list and after selection it opens an application.
I am trying  to locate element in that application.

List < WebElement > productivityButtons = driver.findElements(By.className("app-open-btn"));
for (WebElement item: productivityButtons) {
 String appName = item.getAttribute("appName");
 if (item.getAttribute("appName").equals("ReceiveApp")) {
  item.click();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[id='inputId']")).sendKeys("5900020010000");
 } 
}

Comment: html here                                                                                                
<ion-view view-title="app" hide-back-button="true">
    <div class="bar bar-header pallet-search">
        <div class="list list-inset search-box" ng-show="receive.scanMode">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="inputId" ng-model="nmbr" on-enter="receive.scanItem()" >
            <div class="ion-search custom-search-button" ng-click="SearchMode()"></div>
            <div class="ion-mic-a custom-search-button end-border"></div>
        </div>
 </div>
</ion-view>

Comment: There are no elements there with the class "app-open-btn", or any of the other selectors you're using so that's probably why it's not finding anything...

Comment: app-open-btn is in diff html page I am able to locate that, after the item.click() it comes to the above htmlpage, i have issue there..driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[id='inputId']")).sendKeys("5900020010000");........this is what i have issue

Comment: Why are you using xpath if you have the id? Just use: driver.findElement(By.id("inputId"))

Comment: Ok, when you say it opens an application, do you mean it opens a new browser window?

Comment: And are you actually switching to this new browser window before trying to find the element?

Comment: I've updated my answer with code to switch between browser windows.

Comment: Awesome Josh, that resolved my issue, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Josh,you can use the id,like this:`driver.findElement(By.id("inputId"))`
if you want to use xpath,try it :`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='inputId']"))`